# How does Task Manager gets command line executable path for processes?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm looking at Task Manager's list of processes, and enabled View > Select columns > Command line to see include exe path & command line arguments.

I tried to get the same thing working using `GetModuleFileNameEx` but there's some problems; first, the result doesn't include any arguments and it also fails for some processes, as basic as **WinRar.exe** or **Opera.exe**.

I know that Task Manager uses WMI to get some of this data (I tried shutting down the service and it failed just the way my script did, for the same processes), but I wonder, what makes a process's path "ungettable"?

Comment: Does your process handle have the necessary access rights for `GetModuleFileNameEx`? (PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION and PROCESS_VM_READ)

Comment: Yes, I passed both to `OpenProcess`.

Comment: It is just not available directly from the winapi.  You can get the backdoor to the native api with winternl.h, enough to get this.  But using Win32_Process is the supported way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Task Manager uses the process's [`PEB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813706.aspx) structure to access the command-line arguments (amongst other things).  If you have a `HANDLE` to the target process (and sufficient rights to access its memory), you can access the [`PEB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813706.aspx) using the [`NtQueryInformationProcess()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280.aspx) function (set its `ProcessInformationClass` parameter to `ProcessBasicInformation` to receive a `PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION` structure) to obtain the memory address of the [`PEB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813706.aspx) within the target process's address space (amongst other things).  You can then use `ReadProcessMemory()` to read the contents of the [`PEB`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813706.aspx) into your app's address space as needed.  The command-line parameters are located by using the `PEB::ProcessParameters` field, which is a pointer to a [`RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813741.aspx) structure, which contains a `CommandLine` field of type [`UNICODE_STRING`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380518.aspx).

Things get a little trickier if you are a 32-bit process accessing the PEB of a 64-bit process, or vice versa.  You have to take into account the different sizes of pointers (4 of 32-bit, 8 for 64-bit), which affects structure sizes and offsets.

But this is the gist of it.

Comment: I found this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/11/25/9928372.aspx which provided an example on how to work on the pointer returned by `GetCommandLine()` to alter command-line data.