# Get STARTUPINFO for given process

Tags: c, winapi

Is it possible to get the startup information of another running process? I want to find out the cmd line arguments, if it should be run minimised/maximised, start in directory, run as admin, etc.

Comment: 1. Inject code into target process. 2. Call `GetStartupInfo()` and `GetCommandLine()` from the context of the target process. 3. Pass data back to original process.

Comment: @JonathanPotter thanks for your comment. The purpose is to provide the user with the ability to launch processes (with their correct startup attribs) by clicking a button. Injecting code to get the correct startup attribs would be suspect/flagged by anti-virus programs wouldn't it?

Comment: @JakeM: A process's command-line can be retrieved without using injection, either by [reading the process's `PEB` structure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11042947/65863), or using [WMI](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20091125-00/?p=15923).

Comment: @RemyLebeau and the `STARTUPINFO` ?

Comment: @JonathanPotter sorry, I have no idea where a process's `STARTUPINFO` is stored or how to access it without using injection.

Comment: no direct STARTUPINFO in process but exist RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS - this is what you need. so you can get pointer to process PEB (by query ProcessBasicInformation) and than read virtual memory

Comment: See [Undocumented functions of NTDLL | PEB](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode%2FUndocumented%20Functions%2FNT%20Objects%2FProcess%2FPEB.html) and [Undocumented functions of NTDLL | RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS](http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/index.html?page=UserMode%2FStructures%2FRTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS.html) for more details about the structure contents than MSDN provides.

Answer (score 2):

you need read RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS from remote process. this can be done like this

```
NTSTATUS GetProcessParameters(PCLIENT_ID pcid, PUNICODE_STRING CommandLine)
{
    HANDLE hProcess;
    NTSTATUS status;

    static OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES zoa = { sizeof(zoa)};

    if (0 <= (status = ZwOpenProcess(&hProcess, PROCESS_VM_READ|PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, &zoa, pcid)))
    {
        PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION pbi;
        _RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS ProcessParameters, *pv;
        if (0 <= (status = ZwQueryInformationProcess(hProcess, ProcessBasicInformation, &pbi, sizeof(pbi), 0)))
        {
            if (
                (0 <= (status = ZwReadVirtualMemory(hProcess, (_PEB*)&pbi.PebBaseAddress->ProcessParameters, &pv, sizeof(pv), 0)))
                &&
                (0 <= (status = ZwReadVirtualMemory(hProcess, pv, &ProcessParameters, sizeof(ProcessParameters), 0)))
                )
            {
                if (ProcessParameters.CommandLine.Length)
                {
                    if (CommandLine->Buffer = (PWSTR)LocalAlloc(0, ProcessParameters.CommandLine.Length + sizeof(WCHAR)))
                    {
                        if (0 > (status = ZwReadVirtualMemory(hProcess, ProcessParameters.CommandLine.Buffer, CommandLine->Buffer, ProcessParameters.CommandLine.Length, 0)))
                        {
                            LocalFree(CommandLine->Buffer);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            CommandLine->MaximumLength = (CommandLine->Length = ProcessParameters.CommandLine.Length) + sizeof(WCHAR);
                            *(PWSTR)RtlOffsetToPointer(CommandLine->Buffer, ProcessParameters.CommandLine.Length) = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        status = STATUS_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        ZwClose(hProcess);
    }
    return status;
}
    UNICODE_STRING CommandLine;
    if (0 <= GetProcessParameters(&cid, &CommandLine))
    {
        DbgPrint("CommandLine=%wZ\n", &CommandLine);
        LocalFree(CommandLine.Buffer);
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't help get `STARTUPINFO` which is what the actual question was.

Comment: please look for STARTUPINFO fields and RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS fields - this is almost same. really STARTUPINFO is filled from RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS

Comment: Probably worth mentioning that the documentation says: "The ZwQueryInformationProcess function and the structures that it returns are internal to the operating system and subject to change from one release of Windows to another. To maintain the compatibility of your application, it is better to use public functions mentioned in the description of the ProcessInformationClass parameter instead."

Comment: MSDN wrote this already many years, but in general ZwQueryInformationProcess, RTL_USER_PROCESS_PARAMETERS - not changed how minimum from win2000, when some good documented API, like GetVersion suddenly changed. this code worked from xp up to latest win10. use it or not already private choice